# Why was my question migrated to SU?

Tags: discussion, migration

This question

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/196578/disable-spell-check-when-sending-code-in-outlook

was migrated by a **very-low-rep** user to SU.  Is that supposed to be possible?

This same user then "answered" the question on SU with an answer that illustrates the very reason I wanted the question on Programmers not SU... the answer shows a lack of basic understanding of the unique issues of a programmer.

(He advises me to add to a spell-check dictionary every possible variable and method name I will ever use in the future)

I chose Programmers because I thought that was the best community to understand my problem and have faced it before.  Migrating the question was overly zealous and counter-productive.

Comment: That "very-low-rep" user is a moderator - notice the diamond after the name.

Comment: Also, I don't think 14k rep is "very-low-rep". 14k is quite respectable.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, their rep is 109

Comment: Only on Super User. [See the Programmers.SE profile.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/28988/world-engineer).

Answer (score 5):

Your question was migrated from Programmers by a Programmers moderator. Their reputation on the target site is irrelevant (to the migration process).

As for the migration itself, your question is off topic on Programmers. Disabling the "red spell check squigglies" on Outlook isn't really what I'd call a "conceptual question on software development". If you are looking for a programmatic solution, then your question would be more suitable for Stack Overflow than Programmers. If you decide to post it on Stack Overflow, please take care to mention what you've already tried.

Comment: I wanted a programmer to answer it with a solution that was appropriate to programmers.  The solution that was proposed on SU was not practical for a programmer to use

Comment: @JoelFan I understand what you want, but that doesn't really make your question on topic. Please read our [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) thoroughly to find more details on what the site's about and what questions we welcome.

Comment: @YannisRizos "I wanted a programmer to answer it" it's almost as if the site name is confusing... :)

Comment: @AakashM The name can be confusing for newer users, no argument there. But JoelFan has been a member for over 2 years, and has asked and answered several questions...

Answer (score 3):

The migration was performed by a community moderator and the migration was correct. The question is off-topic per our FAQ - it is not a question about software development that falls within the scope of our site. If that answer is insufficient, you should edit your question on Super User (where questions about programs such as Outlook are on-topic) to add more details.